# php urlencode does not work or is it something else

Tags: php, urlencode

I am trying my hand in PHP and got stuck with the urlencode. Please see the two code

first document@

```
<HTML>
   <HEAD>
      <TITLE>My Movie Site</TITLE>
   </HEAD>
   <BODY>
    <?php 

    // delete as per page 34 define ('FAVMOVIE', 'The life of Brian'); 
    echo    'My favorite movie is ';
    echo    $_GET['favmovie'];
    echo '<br/>';
    $movierate = 5;
    echo 'My movie rating for this movie is: ';
    echo $movierate;
    ?>

   </BODY>
</HTML>
```

Second document

```
<HTML>

   <HEAD>

   <TITLE>Find my Favorite Movie!</TITLE>

   </HEAD>

   <BODY>
            <?php 

                $myfavmovie = urlencode ('Life of Brian');
                echo    '<a href = "http://php.aryapratinidhisabha.org.uk?favmovie=$myfavmovie\">'  ;
                echo    'Click here to see information about my favorite movie!' ;
                echo    '</a>'  ;

            ?>

   </BODY>

</HTML>
```

I am getting the following result all the time:

In the first line: "My favorite movie is $myfavmovie\"

In the second line: "My movie rating for this movie is: 5"

My questoins are:

1. Why am I not getting in the first line: "My favorite movie is Life of Brian"?
2. The book says that in the url the result should be "http://php.aryapratinidhisabha.org.uk/?favmovie=$Life+of+Brian instead it gives this http://php.aryapratinidhisabha.org.uk/?favmovie=$myfavmovie. Why is that?

Thanks,

Naveen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use double apostrophes. Variables aren't evaluated between single ones.

This way:

```
echo    "<a href = \"http://php.aryapratinidhisabha.org.uk?favmovie=$myfavmovie\">"  ;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't insert a string into a string by referencing it like you would do in almost every other case, unless you use double quotes. Meaning that: you should either invert the chain of single and double quotes, like this:

```
echo "<a href='http://php.aryapratinidhisabha.org.uk?favmovie=$myfavmovie'>";
```

or concatenate the strings, like this:

```
echo '<a href="http://php.aryapratinidhisabha.org.uk?favmovie='.$myfavmovie.'">';
```